# How to combine Images to PDF using Prawn?

Tags: ruby, prawn

The below code is able to combine the images but they are not completely fitting in the PDF pages. Is there a setting in Prawn which allows to combine images fitting the page size and exported as PDF ?

```
require 'prawn'
require 'fastimage'

Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf", :page_layout => :landscape) do
(1..40).each do|i|
    size = FastImage.size("./java/sl#{i}.jpg")
    start_new_page(:size => size,:layout => :landscape)         
    image "./java/sl#{i}.jpg"
end
end
```

Comment: RTFM http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Images.html There are options :scale, :fit etc.

Answer (score 0):

try to add some location using `at` attribute for the image

for example:

```
image "./java/sl#{i}.jpg", :at => [x,y]
```

specify the values of `x,y` as per your need.